# minimize boot time for linux

Tags: linux, boot, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded system. The OS is yocto project(Ubuntu). My target hardware has to start the animation application after powered on. I am starting my animation application as a systemd service under basic.target.

But as soon as i powered on the board, a flash screen is coming for some 500ms and after that a cursor is blinking for 10 seconds then my animation application starting. so it is taking around 13 seconds for my animation application to start showing on the screen.

I want to remove that flash screen and cursor blinking. What should i do? 
Is there any way to minimize the kernal bootup time?

The result of systemd-analyze blame is as follows:

```
      1.065s dev-mmcblk1p1.device
      1.004s launchHMIUSB.service
       518ms launchWeston.service
       437ms node-startup-controller.service
       287ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       286ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       279ms pas-daemon.service
       254ms systemd-modules-load.service
       245ms alsa-restore.service
       219ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       219ms connman.service
       207ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       202ms dev-hugepages.mount
       190ms systemd-journald.service
       138ms systemd-sysctl.service
       133ms ofono.service
       127ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
       121ms tmp.mount
       120ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       117ms dev-mqueue.mount
       102ms systemd-logind.service
       101ms node-health-monitor.service
        93ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
        90ms sys-kernel-config.mount
        90ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        88ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        74ms user@0.service
        68ms wpa_supplicant.service
        67ms systemd-udevd.service
        60ms nodestatemanager-daemon.service
        53ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        31ms systemd-random-seed.service
        31ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        18ms sshd.socket
        16ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        16ms Data-mnttemp.mount
        15ms var-volatile.mount
```

Comment: You could have a look at (and edit question to include) results of "systemd-analyse blame" to start, and check this to see if it helps with the blinking cursor : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot#Remove_console_cursor_blinking

Comment: the result of **systemd-analyze blame** is added as asked. The comment systemd-analyze time gives Startup finished in 11.836s (userspace) = 13.877s.

I gone through the link attached above for removing cursor blink but Iam not able to do **export  std_bootarg vt.global_cursor_default=0**. This is showing **bash: export: `vt.global_cursor_default=0': not a valid identifier**. do you have any solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing boot time is step 3. Your steps 1 and 2 are figuring out **what** actually takes so long, and **why**.

The boot process isn't as direct as "power button → kernel → your app". What you get during those first 500ms is your initial firmware; bootloader, if any; and the Linux kernel loading graphics drivers. The rest is 'init' (systemd) starting various services until it gets to the point where it can even begin launching your app.

- Examine system logs to look for the most obvious failures.
- Examine the outputs of `systemd-analyze blame`, `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to look at which systemd units take the longest to start. Figure out why each unit is slow, and whether it is necessary at all. (Most units start in parallel groups. Some are serialized but sometimes needlessly so.)
- Use tools like *bootchartd* to monitor resources during system boot. For example, it could be that your storage is too slow, or that a certain service hogs the CPU for too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked with **systemd-analyze blame** and **systemd-analyze critical-chain lazy.target** comments(lazy.target is the final target which iam starting), it is showing 3s only.

But the comment **systemd-analyze time** gives **Startup finished in 11.836s (userspace) = 13.877s**.    Is this 13.877s is before init process or after init process. If before init process starts, how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor blink has been removed by passing vt.global_cursor_default=0

```
setenv bootargs 'vt.global_cursor_default=0'
saveenv
```